# IDE Freeze Error, a question about a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sum

why whenever I remove,
obj //=10. at line 8 my IDE Freezes when I run this code?

```
def print_sum(obj):

    s = 0

    if isinstance(obj, int):
        while obj:
            s += obj % 10
            obj //= 10 
        print('Sum of digits:', s)

   
print_sum(12345)
```

Can I know what does `obj //= 10` exactly do?
And can you please explain what happens in this function?

Answer (score 1):

because without changing obj you are stuck in a infinite loop.
`obj//=10` integer-divide your obj until it is 0 and the loops ends.

Answer (score 1):

It a short way to write `obj = obj//10` the code freezes because you don't update `obj` and therefore don't exit the while